# How to properly return a large ArrayList through Jersey?

Tags: java, rest, arraylist, jersey

I have a function that would need to return a large ArrayList:

```
    LogData response = (LogData) target.path("logs")
            .queryParam("searchStr", "Some string")
            .request().get(LogData.class);
```

With:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class LogData
{
    private ArrayList<String> listStr;
    private String logStr;

    public ArrayList<String> getLogList()
    {
        return this.listStr;
    }

    public void setLogList(ArrayList<String> listStr)
    {
        this.listStr = listStr;
    }

    public String getLogStr()
    {
        return this.logStr;
    }

    public void setLogStr(String logStr)
    {
        this.logStr = logStr;
    }
}
```

And:

```
@GET
@Path("/logs")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public LogData getAllMatchedStrInLogFile(@QueryParam("searchStr") String searchStr) {

    logger.debug("Check if string \"{}\" is in file {}", searchStr, fileName);
    LogData logsParsed = new LogData();

    ArrayList<String> parsedList = getParsedListStr("myFile.txt", searchStr);
    logsParsed.setLogList(parsedList);
    return logsParsed;
}
```

But I get this exception:

```
Apr 10, 2017 3:51:49 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener start
INFO: Started listener bound to [0.0.0.0:9998]
Apr 10, 2017 3:51:49 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer start
INFO: [RestServer] Started.
Apr 10, 2017 3:52:19 PM org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder writeResponse
SEVERE: An I/O error has occurred while writing a response message entity to the container output stream.
javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.AbstractRootElementJaxbProvider.writeTo(AbstractRootElementJaxbProvider.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:250)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:85)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:621)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:377)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:367)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1030)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:378)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandlerChain.doHandle(HttpHandlerChain.java:197)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.SameThreadIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(SameThreadIOStrategy.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeyEvents(SelectorRunner.java:414)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeys(SelectorRunner.java:383)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.doSelect(SelectorRunner.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.run(SelectorRunner.java:278)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:313)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:236)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.AbstractRootElementJaxbProvider.writeTo(AbstractRootElementJaxbProvider.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.AbstractRootElementJaxbProvider.writeTo(AbstractRootElementJaxbProvider.java:168)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.blockAfterWriteIfNeeded(OutputBuffer.java:973)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:686)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NIOOutputStreamImpl.write(NIOOutputStreamImpl.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.write(CommittingOutputStream.java:229)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableOutputStream.write(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:299)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.output.UTF8XmlOutput.write(UTF8XmlOutput.java:396)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.output.Encoded.write(Encoded.java:152)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.output.UTF8XmlOutput.doText(UTF8XmlOutput.java:308)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.output.UTF8XmlOutput.text(UTF8XmlOutput.java:290)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.text(XMLSerializer.java:391)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$StringImplImpl.writeText(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:1031)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$StringImplImpl.writeText(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:1015)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementLeafProperty.serializeItem(ArrayElementLeafProperty.java:71)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayElementProperty.java:157)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:144)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:345)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(XMLSerializer.java:578)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:479)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:308)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl$Sync.innerGet(SafeFutureImpl.java:357)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl.get(SafeFutureImpl.java:264)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.blockAfterWriteIfNeeded(OutputBuffer.java:962)
    ... 65 more

Apr 10, 2017 3:53:19 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener shutdownNow
INFO: Stopped listener bound to [0.0.0.0:9998]
```

If the returned arraylist size is < 150, it does not return this exception, but if its > 150, it will. So I'm not sure how to extend the timeout or how to enlarge the header to accommodate my large response.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Use pagination.

Comment: use ChunkedOutput in jersey